# Getting null with e.getMessage();

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a simple RSS Reader. I think i done but I get exception with "null" message. JavaDoc said that it is possible to get this value so it's nothing strange. But how could I find out what is wrong with my code? [part 1](http://pastebin.com/dPyh4SD2) [part 2](http://pastebin.com/6QbxdJHA)
and main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("http://facet.wp.pl/rss.xml");
    Feed feed = new Feed();
    RSSParser parser = new RSSParser(url);
    parser.RSSFeed();

    for(String wejscia : feed.entries){
        System.out.println(wejscia);
    }
}
```

@EDIT
The exception is at RSSParser.RSSFeed(RSSParser.java:28) and i have already know that it's a NullPointerException

Comment: So, what is the exception. Where is it thrown? What's the stack trace?

Comment: I managed to pull out that it is java.lang.NullPointerException. Somewhere in RSSFeed's method.

Comment: The stack trace tells you **exactly** wherethe exception is thrown. Read it. And read the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: so I have already know where exactly exception is but still do not know why. I read all the answers in duplicate question but i am still confused.

Comment: The stack trace and the exception stack trace must be **in the question itself**. You claim that the exception is at line 28 of RSSParser.java, and this line, according to what you posted, is `noteName = "description";`. There is no way for this line of code to throw a NPE. Post the real code, and the real stack trace. But before doing that, use your debugger to know what is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Feed class

```
 public static List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In the RssParser change

```
private Feed feed = new Feed();

feed.entries.add(feed.toString());
```

For

```
private Feed feed;
```

and inside the for loop

```
feed = new Feed()
Feed.entries.add(feed.toString());
```

Comment: I did but nothing has changed.

Comment: In the RssFeed comment those lines //noteName = "author"; and
                //feed.setAuthor(partOfObject.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); and see what happens.. I see in the xml  there is no nodes with this names